# Flip the contents of the defined SVG group, but not the group's common offset coordinates

Tags: svg, transform

This could be a fairly common situation.
An SVG drawing has a  reoccurring pattern.  It's defined in the `<defs>`

```svg
<defs>
    <g id="endTip">
        <circle r="2px" fill="blue"/>   <!-- origin mark for the def for debug purposes -->
        <polyline stroke-width="1px" stroke="black" fill="none" points="0,-4 100,-4 100,4 0,4" />
    </g>
</defs>
```

then the pattern is stamped onto the drawing with `<using>`

```
<use x="250px"  y="15px"  xlink:href="#endTip" />                           <!-- right -->
<use x="-250px" y="-15px" xlink:href="#endTip" transform="scale(-1,1)"/>    <!-- left -->
```

Furthermore, I want to horizontally flipped (mirror) some of the instances.  To achieve that, I'm applying a transform in the `<using>` element.  My intent is to transform the contents of the pattern, but keep unchanged the *x* and *y*, which are prescribed in the `<using>` element.  Instead, both the contents and the *x* and *y* are mirrored.

[image]
(Rendered with Chrome version 44.  Green annotations are not the part of SVG.)

What is a good way to flip the contents, but keep the *x* and *y*, which are prescribed in the `<using>` element unflipped?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau  Thanks for the link to that thread.  I have tried your method with `translate(<2 * centreX>,0) scale(-1, 1)`, which you have described in your answer in that thread.  It works.  In my case, I don't have to flip about the middle, so `<2 * centreX>` becomes `<2 * x>`.  But I have to manually calculate and type that in for each instance.

Comment: That will be the case I'm afraid.  There is no auto-magic way to flip in place an arbitrary element.

Comment: Except if you're creating the original objects and you take care to draw them all centred on their local coordinate origin.